# dotenv not installed under Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to get paperless installed, and am running into an issue with dotenv under python.  I've some digging, and ended up doing an uninstall of dotenv and then an install of python-dotenv via pip.  I'm still running into the same error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/paperless/paperless/src/paperless/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

I'm running
Linux ubuntu 4.13.0-21-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 18 17:29:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Python 3.6.3

pip install python-dotenv returns Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.8.2

Comment: @Makoto Consider rephrasing to be less sarcastic.

Comment: @user1114:  It's a very genuine question.  The issue here is that the module is missing.  `pip3 install dotenv` is the way to install that module.  I'm really not sure what's being asked; the fact is that the module isn't installed and the only way to address the problem would be...to install it.  Also, I can't edit that comment anymore.

Comment: @makoto I'm sorry - I had intended to convey that I did pip uninstall dotenv, pip uninstall python-dotenv, and finally pip install python-dotenv.  I should've worded my question more clearly.  That was the most commonly found solution, but it does not work in my case.

Comment: Let's drill down a bit more specific.  What do you see when the installation fails?  Do you have a `~/.pip/pip.conf` file?

Comment: I don't appear to have a pip.conf file.  The installation of python-dotenv is successful (or at least doesn't throw errors).  It ends with: Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.8.2

Comment: (You should be adding details to your question, not comments.)  So even after you install it, you still get that error?  Which environment did you install it to - did you install it to your virtual environment?  Is it active when you perform the `pip install` command?

Comment: Correct.  I didn't select an environment - I'm not familiar with django/pip and was following a guide.  It sounds like that may be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First check for dotenv with 'pip3 list'

install it if not on the list with: 'pip3 install python-dotenv'

Results:
Collecting python-dotenv
Downloading python_dotenv-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
**Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.20.0**

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with installing it from my project directory.

Go to the root directory(cd /) and then 'pip3 install python-dotenv' that helped me.